# Read object attributes from a database in Python

Tags: python, database, object

I have a class item that is:

```
class Item: #This item is for the contents of a given site.
    def __init__(self, site, username, password):
        self.site = site #Each site should have a unique name
        self.username = username #site username/email
        self.password = password #site password
```

And save it to a database and can retrieve it without any issues, however I then use a for each loop to read each item individually (which also works) but then when I try to access a given attribure e.g. password i get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'password'
```

This is my read code:

```
def read():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="user",
        passwd="pass",
        database="thisDb"
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM data")

    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult:
        print(x.password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly suggest not using `*`, but declaring the columns. As the `fetchall()` method returns a list of tuples. If you know which columns there are you can unpack the result like this.

```
for x in myresult:
    column1, column2, column3 = x
```

Comment: I know using * is bad practice but I only store three columns in the database and need them al to be displayed. But thank you this solves my problem

Answer (score 2):

The [`fetchall()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) method returns a `list` of `tuples`. From the docs:

> The method fetches all (or all remaining) rows of a query result set
>   and returns a list of tuples. If no more rows are available, it
>   returns an empty list.

So in this section of your code:

```
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
    print(x.password)
```

`myresult` is a list, and `x` is a `tuple`.

Instead of using a raw cursor, there is the [MySQLCursorNamedTuple](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursornamedtuple.html) cursor class. That will let you access the columns with attribute lookup syntax without having to instantiate a class.

Here is the documented example:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(database='world')
cursor = cnx.cursor(named_tuple=True)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM country WHERE Continent = 'Europe'")

print("Countries in Europe with population:")
for row in cursor:
    print("* {Name}: {Population}".format(
        Name=row.Name,
        Population=row.Population
    ))
```

Also, you could try the [`MySQLCursorDict`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html) which will return a mapping of the column names to values.

You could then easily convert the `dict` result to an instance of your object, e.g.:

```
myresult = dictcursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
    inst = Item(**x)
    print(inst.password)
```

Or, use an ORM like [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html) which sounds like it might suit your needs.

Comment: I didn't see it at first glance, but you should use the `namedtuple` type of cursor. Then you get class style attribute lookup without any extra work.